# REACTJS .join() not working in app.js but working in other .js components ERROR:TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the icon from fontawesome through a state object where I keep the class names and change them on a click.

i have a state like this

```
infoMobile: ["fas", "fa-info-circle", "info_mobile"],
```

and i have this function, where i change the InfoMobile

```
openAboutContactMob = () => {
   const {navKlasa} = this.state;
   navKlasa.push("mobile_remove");
   this.setState({navKlasa: navKlasa});

   var {infoMobile} = this.state;
   infoMobile = ["fas", "fa-times-circle", "info_mobile"];
   this.setState({infoMobile: infoMobile});
}
```

all of this is in the app.js file, also in the return i am using it like this

```
<div className="mobile_nav_bckg"><i onClick={this.openAboutContactMob} className={this.infoMobile.join(' ')}></i></div>
```

when I click on the icon I want to change the classes so the icon changes but I get the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

This may be obvious but I'm new at this so any advice would do, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference state

```
<div className="mobile_nav_bckg"><i onClick={this.openAboutContactMob} className={this.state.infoMobile.join(' ')}></i></div>
```

See `this.state.infoMobile` instead of `this.infoMobile`

That is because setState (used here) `this.setState({infoMobile: infoMobile});` is a function that React provides to update state. 
Another thing is that there is no need to reference your previous state as you're doing it here

```
var {infoMobile} = this.state;
infoMobile = ["fas", "fa-times-circle", "info_mobile"];
this.setState({infoMobile: infoMobile});
```

You could directly set it

```
this.setState({infoMobile: ["fas", "fa-times-circle", "info_mobile"] });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. One more question while we're at it, what would be the best way to change between the two states (one would be classes with "fa-times-circle" and the other with "fa-info-circle". I want it to happen on the same click. @Gonzalo.-

Comment: you should probably verify your current state and set the other. Don't reference state directly, use the callback format for the setState function. `this.setState(prevState => /** check prevState and return new one based on that */)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to reference state. Try `className={this.state.infoMobile.join('')}`